# peewee one-to-many as collection

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, orm, peewee

I want to implement such a model with Pewee/Python3.
There is a users, who need to post messages into different channels.
So, there must be two tables: **channels** and **users**. If simplified, it looks like that:

**channels**
PK channel_id: *int* 
   channel_name: *string* 
   title: *string*

**users** 
PK user_id: *int* 
   user_name: *string* 
FK channels: *list of channels*

I suppose It should look like that:

```
class Channel(BaseModel):
    channel_id = PrimaryKeyField()
    user = ForeignKeyField(User, backref='user')
    channel_name = CharField()
    title = CharField()


class User(BaseModel):
    user_id = PrimaryKeyField()
    user_name = CharField()
    title = CharField()
    channels = ForeignKeyField(Channel, backref='channels', null=True)
```

And I want it to be accessible as a common python list, like

```
some_user.channels.add(sample_channel)
...
for channel in some_user.channels:
    ...
```

etc.
But I am unable to use ***User.channels*** as a collection. 
How can I implement it using Peewee?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a many-to-many relationship:

```
class Channel(Model):
    name = CharField()

class User(Model):
    username = CharField()

class UserChannel(Model):
    user = ForeignKeyField(User, backref='user_channels')
    channel = ForeignKeyField(Channel, backref='channel_users')

# get channels for a user named 'huey'
huey_channels = (Channel
                 .select()
                 .join(UserChannel)
                 .join(User)
                 .where(User.username == 'huey'))
```